# I try to build webrtc in using xcode,but missing rtc_base_approved_generic.a,How to fix it?

Tags: xcode, webrtc, ninja

```
build rtc_base_approved_generic: phony obj/rtc_base/rtc_base_approved_generic.stamp
```

what is `rtc_base_approved_generic.stamp` and what is it used for?
`rtc_base_approved_generic.stamp` is empty，why the script does not create `rtc_base_approved_generic.a`. Will appreciated for any help.

Comment: The formatting of your question is very poor. I cannot make out what's supposed to be a code snippet, and what the actual question.

Comment: when you try to build webrtc,you will find build.ninja script.use it to build. but some syntaxes that I do not understand. suck as  "build rtc_base_approved_generic: phony obj/rtc_base/rtc_base_approved_generic.stamp",what is different between it and "build rtc_base_generic: phony obj/rtc_base/librtc_base_generic.a".